# How to add searchable text to an image?

Tags: images, text

I need to add text to an image (original image can be jpg, gif, or bmp) file, how can I do it? I added the texts with shutter to an jpg and converted to pdf. Tesseract has not been able to turn the text in these images into a real text.  It seems easier to add a text that is already searchable to the image (instead of adding and processing it with OCR). Is my only option creating a pdf and adding the image and the text to it? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I am not sure but there are several other similar [tools](http://askubuntu.com/a/59394/334241).

Comment: What do you mean "add text"? If you've just written some characters on an image, that is not text, that's an image of text. You will need [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) software to recognize it. If you are using a format that supports text as text (such as PDF), then it's completely different but converting a JPG to a PDF won't help.

Comment: @Ramesh: yes, those are a posibility, but since I have the image and want to add a text, couldn't this text be searchable from the beginning. The OCR won't work 100%, contraty to making things right from the beginning. That's different from processing an image that someone else did.

Comment: @terdon: I am aware that I am adding an image of text. I want to add real text to an image.

Comment: OK, then please [edit] your question and clarify. You can't add "real" text to png, bmp or jpg images, the formats don't support it. If that's what you have, OCR is the only option. If you are starting with PDF or svg or other more complex formats, that's a different issue.

Comment: @terdon, done..

Comment: Note that GIF format supports textual comments, and that JPG files can contain EXIF information, which can include text. AFAIK it can't be done in BMP except possibly by writing the text to the end of the file (`echo "The quick brown" >> fox.bmp`), which shouldn't affect the display of the image, but will probably be discarded by any editing.

Answer (score 2):

Image formats such as JPEG and TIFF can include [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data. EXIF was designed for metadata such as the date and location where a photo was taken, copyright information, etc. You can add the text under the “Description” tag.

You can use tools such as [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), [exif](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libexif) or [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) to inject and extract EXIF data.

```
exiftool -description=wibble foo.jpg
exiftool -description foo.jpg
```